# Azure New Portal web apps missing

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azureportal

I have a number of web apps that I can see and on the old Azure management website, but these don't appear in the new portal, in Cloud Explorer in Visual Studio and the Azure App Service Support website.

Any help in getting this sorted out would be much appreciated.

Comment: Anyone experiencing a similar issue to the issue I experienced above should log the issue on [Azure Forum](http://%20https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/home?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview).

Answer (score 1):

just to validate, are you in the same subscription?
You can change your active subscription by clicking on the top-right corner.

[image]

If you are, please select the `All resources` option in the left pane menu.
If it's still not present can you tell us more about what is the "webApp" you don't see?

Comment: I am in the same subscription. What information do you need about the web app.  Would you need the name?

Comment: @Andrew are they worker role/ web role? Are you the owner of the subscription?

Comment: I managed to get the Azure team to sync my account and all are working now.