# missing web apps in new azure portal

Tags: azure, azureportal

I have created two web apps in Azure about two years ago.
I can see the web site now,
but in the new Azure portal the web apps is missing. 
Do you have any idea to show them in the portal.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38507190/azure-new-portal-web-apps-missing

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are in the right subscription, and select "All Resources". If you still can't find, consider going to MSDN forum and the Azure guys might be able to help you. [MSDN Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/home?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview)